# Is it possible to set the skip in a foreach loop and then have it skip each time the page is reloded

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I need to create a foreach loop like this

```
foreach(var row in data.skip(200))
{
  ..this 
}
```

Then once the loop has finished I want the next refresh or page load to be

```
foreach(var row in data.skip(400))
{
  ..this 
}
```

Is there some method witch can rewrite a line of code? or modify a line of code upon completion of my foreach loop? I tried searching but didn't come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want to implement paging.

You can do that for example using a query string parameter.

```
int skip = 0;
int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["skip"], out skip);

foreach(var row in data.skip(skip))
{
    // ...
}

skip += 200;
```

And then you assign `skip` to a variable on your page, so the link to the next page will have `&skip=200` in its URL.